# Python http request not returning json output

Tags: python, json, request

When I am using following command, I get proper json response from the url:
`curl --user user:password -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -X GET <url>`

> "body": {
> "items": [
> {........}]}

However, when I am trying to do same using python request module

```js
import requests

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

user='admin'
password='yanQE3B'
url=<requestUrl>

response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password) , verify=False)

print ( response.content )  ## prints html content

print ( response.text )     ## prints html content

data = response.json()    ## error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

- when i do request.json() , I get an error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
- when i print request.content - it returns html list with html content.
  Output of reponse.text and response.content is same. Truncated html as large number of li tags get returned :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Data</title>
</head>
<div>
<ul>
<li>
body&nbsp;
<ul>
<li>items&nbsp;<ol>
<li>
<ul>
<li>name&nbsp;........ </li><li>messages&nbsp;<ol>
</ol></li></ul></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

headers={'Accept':'application/json'} added to requests.get

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the URL you are trying to get JSON from is by default returning the HTML page only.

From the curl request where you have explicitly passed the content type `application/json` hence you need to similarly update your request statement as below:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password), verify=False, 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

> Note: Above method works only if your URL actually returns the JSON response.

Comment: i used headers={'Accept':'application/json'} which resolved the issue. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @cool_stuff_coming Also, it is preferred to use post method as you are using authentication with username and password!